# Is ksh on AIX in violation of POSIX.1-2004 and POSIX.1-2008?

Tags: shell, posix, aix

I have the following shell script saved in a file called foo.sh.

```
username=$1
if [ -n "$username" ]
then
    echo username: "$username"
fi
```

I am running this script on an AIX 5.3 machine.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/ksh
$ sh foo.sh humpty
username: humpty
$ sh foo.sh =
foo.sh[2]: test: 0403-004 Specify a parameter with this command.
$ ksh foo.sh =
foo.sh[2]: test: 0403-004 Specify a parameter with this command.
$ ksh93 foo.sh =
username: =
$ bash foo.sh =
username: =
```

If you want to know the versions.

```
$ ksh93 -c 'echo ${.sh.version}'
Version M-12/28/93e
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.16(1)-release (powerpc-ibm-aix5.2.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc
```

I could not find a way to determine the version of `ksh`.

As you can see, the script causes an error with `ksh` when I specify `=` as input. I can reproduce this error with ksh on AIX 5.3 but not with bash or ksh93 on AIX 5.3. Perhaps, when the ksh on AIX sees `[ -n = ]`, it expects it to be a test for two identical strings.

Isn't the ksh behaviour in violation of POSIX.1-2004 as well as POSIX.1-2008? The document at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html clearly states this.

> The algorithm for determining the precedence of the operators and the
>   return value that shall be generated is based on the number of
>   arguments presented to test. (However, when using the "[...]" form,
>   the right-bracket final argument shall not be counted in this
>   algorithm.)
>
> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments
>   presented to test:
>
> 0 arguments:
>   Exit false (1).
>
> 1 argument:
>   Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.
>
> 2 arguments:
>
> - If $1 is '!', exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.
> - If $1 is a unary primary, exit true if the unary test is true, false
>     if the unary test is false.
> - Otherwise, produce unspecified results.

In this case, `[ -n = ]` has indeed 2 arguments, and the first argument is indeed a unary primary, so it should test that `=` is non zero string and exit true instead of throwing an error.

Comment: What shell is `/bin/sh`?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. `/bin/sh` on Solaris 8 and Solaris 10 are similarly "vulnerable": `username="="; test -n "$username" && echo ok` -- `test: argument expected`. Solaris 10 `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` echos "ok"

Comment: @EtanReisner, I think it's the venerable Bourne shell.

Comment: @glennjackman That was my assumption. I was mostly trying to clarify the distinction between the current shell and `/bin/sh` but the recent edit fixes that.

Comment: @EtanReisner /bin/sh and /bin/ksh are same. They have the same inode number.

Comment: See also: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/